# Remove overlaping tuple ranges from list leaving only the longest range

Tags: python

For a given list of range-tuples, I need to remove overlapping rage tuples while leaving the longest range for those that overlap or if same length keep both.

eg

```
input = [ [(1, 7), (2, 3),  (7, 8), (9, 20)], [(4, 7), (2, 3),  (7, 10)], [(1, 7), (2, 3),  (7, 8)]]

expected_output = [ [(1,7), (9,20)], [(4,7), (2, 3), (7,10)], [(1,7)] ]
```

so **only the longest overlapping range-tuple should not be removed**.

```
def overlap(x:tuple, y:tuple) -> bool:
    return  bool(len( range(max(x[0],y[0]), min(x[1], y[1])+1  ) ))

def drop_overlaps(tuples: list):

    def other_tuples(elems: list, t: tuple)-> list:
        return [e for e in elems if e != t]
        
    return [ t for t in tuples if not any( overlap(t, other_tuple) 
                                            for other_tuple in other_tuples(tuples, t))  ]
```

How do I remove the overlaps and keep the longest of them and those that are non-overlapping?

Comment: can you show the code you have tried to solve this

Comment: @deadshot Sure just edited

Comment: Why is `(7, 8)` dropped in the first example?

Comment: @quamrana as it overlaps with `(1,7)` and `(1,7)` range is longer (7) than `(7,8)` which is of length 2. We want to keep only the longest from the overlapping tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the tuple based on the first key, Then compare using your `overlap` function and check the difference and add the values to result based on the difference. If the difference is equal add  value to result list otherwise replace last element in result with max value.

```
def drop(lst):
    sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
    diff = lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1])
    res = [sorted_lst[0]]
    for x in sorted_lst[1:]:    
        if overlap(res[-1], x):
            if diff(res[-1]) == diff(x):
                res.append(x)
            else:
                res[-1] = max(res[-1], x, key=diff)
        else:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```